# .h264 file cannot convert to .mp4 file by using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, h.265

I have a car camera. Videos are **HEVC** codec but stored with **.h264** file type. 
I use ffmpeg to convert these .h264 file type to mp4 file type.

Most of videos are converted successfully, some videos failed.

[some video convert successfully, some video failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXchi.png)

What is weird is that this "convert-failed" video clip can be normally played by using the video player provided from video seller.
[convert-failed video clip be played successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXp40.jpg)

I will upload two of these **.h264** videos, one can be converted successfully, one cannot.

Could anyone let me know how to finish the convert.

see my ffmpeg command and output here
https://github.com/Pinocchio2018/h264ConvertedFailVideo.git

Comment: Try: `ffmpeg -y -f hevc -i ./060322_010.h264 -c copy output-fail.mp4`. `-f hevc` marks input the file format as HEVC. `-c copy` only wraps ("muxing") the video stream with MP4 container (without re-encoding).